# Sign and Distribute button greyed out for iOS IPA in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, publish

When trying to publish iOS IPA with Xamarin to TestFlight the button 'Sign and Distribute' is greyed out. This is since a couple of days. The provisioning profile (Signing Identity and Provisioning profile) in the build settings are the same as selected in the 'Sign and Distribute' settings.
Also with new provisioning certificates the result is the same.
When the project is opened on other machines the problem persists.
The bundle identifier is the same in the info.plist as in the certificates.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the build settings for the IPA to random values. Then clean and build the project. Restart Xamarin. After that set the build settings correct again. Then clean and build again. When the Sign and Distribute button is still grey again, switch between the available provisioning profiles multiple times. And then the button will get enabled.